# Python custom sort key raises `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list of mixed data types such as this.

```py
a = [False, [1, 2, 1], {2: 2, 1: 1}, 2, "c", ["z", "a"],  1, "a", ["3", "7"], {"a": "a"}]
```

I want to sort it. So I created this custom key function to pass to the sort function.

```py
def sorter(item):
    if isinstance(item, Number) and not isinstance(item, bool):
        return 0, item
    elif isinstance(item, str):
        return 1, item
    elif isinstance(item, bool):
        return 2, item
    elif isinstance(item, list):
        item.sort(key=sorter)
        return 3, item
    elif isinstance(item, dict):
        return 4, item
    else:
        return 5, item
```

The problem is that when it wants to sort the members of the same type which may have sub-members (like lists and dicts), it compares them together and if if the data types of the members of the two compared elements (two lists or two dicts) are different, it raises a `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` exception. If anybody knows a way around this I will greatly appreciate their assistance.

Comment: Define a key function to use with list.sort or sorted: `def key(x): if isinstance(x, dict): return (str(type(x)), [(key(k), key(v)) for k, v in x.items()]) elif isinstance(x, list): return (str(type(x)), [key(y) for y in x]) else: return (str(type(x)), x)`; and then you can sort with `a.sort(key=key)` or `b = sorted(a, key=key)`

Comment: @Stef Interesting idea. Let me try it and be back.